# Typing a union symbol in R

Tags: r, union

I am trying to type a union symbol in an R graph, as in A \cup B.
Do you know how to do that?

Answer (score 8):

This should work:

```
plot(1:10, main = expression(A*union(B)))
```

Comment: Better than @James because no unnecessary quotes.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use `expression`. It's a bit fiddly, but try this:

```
plot.new()
text(0.5,0.5,expression(paste("A",union(B))))
```

See `?plotmath` for more details.

Comment: Ninja'd  by 10 seconds!  I'll only add that you can use any symbol font element via the `symbol("\042")` method as described in the help page.

Comment: Fastest shuriken in the East ;)